# Fiddler: show only the following hosts doesn't work

Tags: fiddler

In Fiddler's Filters tab, I have "Use Filters" checked off.

I have no zone filter.

I have chosen "Show only the following hosts" and have added the host name that I want to show exactly as it is displayed in Fiddler's "Host" column in the Web Sessions window.

It's not working at all.

I have Fiddler set up to capture all processes.

I'd also like to get Fiddler to show a couple of different hosts

Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: You asked the same question over in the Fiddler forum and haven't answered any of the followup questions that were asked.

Comment: When this question remained unanswered on this forum, I asked on the Fiddler forum. And I did answer at least one of the followup questions on the Fiddler forum, indicating that I would be using another method. I can understand some impatience here but let's make sure the record is accurate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Fiddler's Filters tab, I have "Use Filters" checked off.
->checked off? should be on.

I have chosen "Show only the following hosts" and have added the host name that I want to show exactly as it is displayed in Fiddler's "Host" column in the Web Sessions window.
->make sure you didn't add the 'http://' before it

I'd also like to get Fiddler to show a couple of different hosts
->just separate them with a space or colon.

good luck!

Comment: Elva - that worked. I must have been adding the http:// in earlier tries.  Thanks for your helpful response.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the "use filters" checkbox. 
In the "Show only the following hosts" textbox, type the names of the hosts separated by colon. If you have several similar hosts then you can use wildcards also(see below for an example).

[image: Fiddler's Filter tab]

Comment: AHH wildcards! This was my issue with a subdomain not matching without the *.